# Django error "detail: Credentials were not provided" when trying to logout

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I created a class-based LogoutAPIView but when I test it, it gives the "detail: Credentials were not provided error".

views.py:

```
class LogoutView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    http_method_names = ['post']
    def post(self, request):
        token = request.auth
        if token:
            Token.objects.get(token=token).delete()
            content = {'message': 'Logout successful'}
        else:
            content = {'message': 'No authentication token found'}
        return Response(content)
```

serializer.py:

```
class LogoutSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    message = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
```

My LoginAPIView incase needed:

views.py:

```
class LoginAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = LoginAPISerializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        login(request, user)

        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({'token': token.key}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

serializers.py:

```
class LoginAPISerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']

    def validate(self, data):
        username = data.get('username')
        password = data.get('password')

        if not username or not password:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Username and password are required')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if not user:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Invalid credentials')

        data['user'] = user
        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):

        user = validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return {'token': token.key}
```

I am new to Django, so I don't even know if I need a serializer class for LogoutAPIView. I also added DEAFULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES but it didn't solve the issue. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Alright I already fixed it. Thanks everyone!